# Is the communication between primary and active secondary secured and how it works

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, database-replication, geo-replication

Premium service tier of Azure SQL database provides active geo replication due which upto 4 readable secondaries can be created. I want to know if the communication between primary and secondary database is secure and are there any chances of data being hacked in the transit?

Comment: It would be of great help if anyone can tell how the communication between primary and secondary works

Comment: They follow the same security like when you're connecting to your primary, has to be. I can't find resources online. Perhaps you could contact support?

Answer (score 0):

For more infomation:[Azure SQL Database Inside#High Availability](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1695.inside-microsoft-azure-sql-database.aspx#High_Availability_with_SQL_Azure)

> First, a transaction is not considered to be committed unless the
>   primary replica and at least one secondary replica can confirm that
>   the transaction log records were successfully written to disk. Second,
>   if both a primary replica and a secondary replica must report success,
>   small failures that might not prevent a transaction from committing
>   but that might point to a growing problem can be detected.